# Selecting the table row with the greatest id value

Tags: mysql, database, select

I am trying to write mysql statement that selects the last added value from the table.
Since the id column in my table is an auto increment value, I find that the easiest way to do this is selecting the row with the highest ID value.

I was wondering if anyone can help me accomplish this?

Something like this:

mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table WHERE id=max(id)"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MAX is an aggregate/group function you can't use like this

try this

```
SELECT * 
FROM blog 
ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1;
```

OR

```
SELECT * 
FROM blog 
where id=LAST_INSERT_ID();
```

OR

```
SELECT *
FROM blog 
WHERE (id = (SELECT MAX(id) FROM blog LIMIT 1))
```

Comment: I appreciate the response. I'll give that a try. Is there a reason that you know of, why my query does not work? I am aware that mySQL has a MAX function...?

Comment: MAX is group function, you cant use in this fashion

Answer (score 1):

You can use  `LAST_INSERT_ID()` to find last inserted id.Hence, your query can be like this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM blog 
where id=LAST_INSERT_ID();
```

To work with your query, you have to do like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM blog
WHERE id=(
    SELECT max(id) FROM blog
    )
```

Comment: for some reason, that is not returning anything, as of right now I only have 1 row, but it should still return it, and it returns nothing, I am not getting any error though when I try to access it with PHP's row['id']

Answer (score 0):

After your query execution write:

```
$id = mysql_insert_id();
```

to get id of the last inserted record.